# Google Play Console - Translation Service: Can I describe my strings inside xml file?

Tags: android, google-play, translation, google-play-console

I want to use translation service. When I'm adding `strings.xml` file I can see **"Provide descriptions for your strings to improve translation quality"** and the button **"ADD DESCRIPTIONS"**. But if I add few comments `<!-- -->` to my strings.xml file and re-upload the file there is no "Provide descriptions for your strings to improve translation quality" message.

Does it mean that I can describe my strings inside `strings.xml` file by adding comments above every single string? Is there any official information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documentation is not very easy to find!

All the documentation for this service [is here](https://support.google.com/l10n/answer/6359997). [The specific parts](https://support.google.com/l10n/answer/6272776?hl=en&ref_topic=6307483) about helping the translators by providing descriptions and screenshots link to the [Android localization checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/localization-checklist#manage-strings). If you click on "Manage your app's UI Strings" you get to [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#managing-strings-for-localization). Scroll down to where it says "Provide sufficient context for declared strings" and it says:

## Provide sufficient context for declared strings

As you declare strings in your strings.xml file, make sure to describe the context in which the string is used. This information is invaluable to the translator and result in better quality translation. It also helps you manage your strings more effectively.

Here is an example:

```
<!-- The action for submitting a form. This text is on a button that can fit 30 chars -->
<string name="login_submit_button">Sign in</string>
```

Consider providing context information that may include:

- What is this string for? When and where is it presented to the user?
- Where is this in the layout? For example, translations are less flexible in buttons than in text boxes.

Comment: I agree, it is very difficult to find the documentation. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: How to provide comments if we don't provide a xml file but a csv file ? (csv is the 2nd format that is accepted by the Google Play Translation Service)